# nodejs server get timestamp every hour

Tags: node.js, momentjs

Is there any way that I could get the timestamp every hour after running the NodeJS Server?

Because after starting the server, the variable new Date() won't update.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because after starting the server, the variable new Date() won't update.

I'm not entirely sure of your use case and you haven't provided any code so difficult to know exactly what you are doing.

You can always do `new Date()` again, to get a new date at current time. Or just do `Date.now()` if you want a timestamp. Just combine this with a `setInterval` and you should be golden

```
setInterval(() => console.log(Date.now()), 3600 * 1000)
```

Comment: I've read setInterval() docs but still quite not sure if it blocks the event loop?

Currently, my code depends on the socket.emit from my client just to update the date. :( (because I don't know how to update the date automatically) By that emit, the server listen to it and update the variable and run the function again. Thanks. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: It doesn't block the event loop.